# How do I make ALSA upmix 2.0 to 2.1?

Tags: alsa

For ages, I have been tinkering with ALSA and for an equally long time, I have been frustrated by the rather opaque configuration system it uses. It is really powerful, no doubt, but getting what I want is *difficult*.

Basically, I want my plain stereo setup to be expanded a bit with a subwoofer to add a bit more club-like sound at times. The audio sources I use do not have a sub channel, however, so how do I...

- Upmix my regular 2.0 stereo sources to 2.1 (where the .1 is the sub
  channel)
- Filter the sub channel so the sub only handles low
  frequencies (i.e. make a crossover filter)

ALSA has the `upmix` and `ladspa` plugins. One handles mixing channels while the other is able to apply a variety of digital signal processing filters. I have tried and tried but ALSA kept throwing really hard to interpret errors at me. I have had upmixing and filtering work separately, but chaining them together never went well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration below handles my situation just right, and is based on [this post](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-836457-view-next.html) which describes something very similar. I will comment on the different sections to convey the bits that I *do* understand. Some of it, I don't really get but I accept that they are necessary to make things work. Please add explanations if you are able to refine further upon this:

ALSA configurations are basically a chain of blocks that refer to each other. One block hands off a set of audio channels to be processed by another by referring to the next block in line with the `slave` tag. The first tag in my config specifies the default device, i.e. the audio device apps use if nothing else is specified

```
pcm.!default "plug:upmix21"
```

The `upmix` plugin handles mixing the input channels to a different number of channels. Here, we go from 2.0 to 5.1, since the `upmix` plugin only handles n channels where n%2=0 and because it lets me avoid using a `route` plugin that I never managed to get working

```
pcm.upmix21 {
  type upmix
  slave.pcm "lowpass_51to51_plug"
  delay 0
  channels 6
}
```

The `pcm.lowpass_51to51_plug` is a syntactic necessity because the `upmix21` block only seems to accept `plug` type blocks as slaves.

```
pcm.lowpass_51to51_plug { 
  type plug 
  slave.pcm "lowpass_51to51" 
}
```

This bit handles invoking the LADSPA filters. There are quite a few of them. On Ubuntu, Raspian and so on, they come with the `cmt` and `swh-plugins` packages. They can be used for all sorts of things - ALSA is just one. On your installation, you should check that `path` points to whereever the `ladspa` filters live on your system.

In this configuration, I use two plugins, referred to by their IDs. `1098` is a passthrough filter that just copies input to output, but without it, channels not specifically mentioned will get no sound. The syntax is a little odd, because even though you only specify input and output channel 0, all channels are copied. That is just how it works, apparently. Filter 1051 is a low pass filter that accepts a crossover frequency - 120Hz in my case. I apply it to channel 5, i.e. the LFE or subwoofer channel in the upmixed stereo signal.

```
pcm.lowpass_51to51 { 
   type ladspa 
   slave.pcm "upmix_51to51_float" 
   path "/usr/lib/ladspa" 
   channels 6
   plugins { 
      0 { 
         id 1098  # Identity (Audio) (1098/identity_audio) 
         policy duplicate 
         input.bindings.0 "Input"; 
         output.bindings.0 "Output"; 
      } 

      1 { 
         id 1051  # Low-pass filter. 
         policy none 
         input.bindings.5 "Input"; 
         output.bindings.5 "Output"; 
         input { 
            controls [ 120 ] # No higher than 120 Hz - nothing good.
         } 
      } 
   } 
}
```

This next bit I don't quite get but it is necessary - otherwise, ALSA will barf, saying something about format incompatibility. Basically, we set the audio format to `S16_LE` (stereo 16 bit low-endian?). I would think that this had been established already, but I accept that I need this - please add an explanation here if you can.

```
pcm.upmix_51to51_float { 
  type lfloat 
  slave.pcm "21route" 
  slave.format "S16_LE" 
}
```

As I was testing, I actually used a 5.1 setup to figure out what did and did not work. This block lets me mute channels I don't want. The `ttable` holds the mappings in the form `<input channel>.<output channel> <volume>`. This is actually the final block as it's slave is `surround51` - a pcm device that comes with my ASUS Xonar U7 sound card. Check `aplay -l` and `aplay -L` to see what your devices are called.

```
pcm.21route {
  type route
  slave.pcm "surround51"
  ttable {
        0.0     1       # left channel
        1.1     1       # right channel
        2.2 0           # mute
        3.3 0           # mute
        4.4 0           # mute
        5.5 1           # sub channel
  }
}
```

That is it. I don't know how long time I have spent on this in total. It has been an on and off project for a long time, but now it is actually working. I hope this helps someone spend less time on this than I have.

As a side note, I have `mpd` and `upmpdcli` running on top of this on a RasPi 2. Using BubbleUPNP on Android and SWYH on Windows, this lets me stream Google Music, my own media and almost anything else to my super swanky setup. Yay!

**EDIT:** Things I still need to do:

- I actually don't have a volume control that works with BubbleUPNP
  yet. I need a proper ALSA `ctl` definition. Not a big problem really - I just use `alsamixer` to crank up the volume to 100% per default - then I *manually* (yes, shocking) adjust the volume on my amplifier.
- I want to be able to redirect *all* audio from my Android devices,
  but I can only do this using rooted devices and the `Xposed`
  framework. That works very well, but I want to be able to do this wo.
  the root stuff.